# Open source survey/questionnaire engine for Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, survey

Is there an open source survey engine for java that will allow branching of questions? i.e. Question 1 has the options of A, B, or C and they each take you to a different set of follow-up questions.

I've found a couple (JSurveyLib and Socrates QE), but those seem to be very tied to a GUI.

The application that I'm writing has a java back-end running on glassfish, and a flex front-end. Eventually there are plans for different font-ends, so the engine needs to be very independent of the GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at [JCaiF](http://jcaif.sourceforge.net/jcaif.html) - "The Java Computer Aided Interviewing Framework (JCaiF) is a collection of Java interfaces that define the common elements of a questionnaire or survey" - so perhaps you can implement your application against these interfaces.

Comment: Looks to be like what I need, thanks. Too bad the documentation/sample code is non-existent.