# Survey/questionnaire system for dynamically integrating answers from SQLite database or CouchDB

Tags: java, html, sqlite, couchdb, survey

I am currently working at my master thesis for which I had to implement an android application. In a next step, I will conduct a user study in which, besides others, I have to perform a survey integrating and evaluating data gathered via the aforementioned application. For this, I am looking for a system/library/service capable of doing this with as less additional effort as possible. By now, I came across **JSurveyLib** but admittedly I have only played around with it a little, yet. Is there someone who has experiences with this library and can tell me whether there is an efficient way to use this lib regarding the following specifications and requirements?

To the relevant specifications:
I have implemented an Android app that tracks data of the participant, stores it in an **SQLite** database, and additionally uploads it to a remote **CouchDB**. As soon as the data collection is finished, I have to perform a survey with each participant generically integrating the data previously gathered via the particular participant's device. For this, I got two basic scenarios:

### List-Scenario:

1. Get the data stored in the database that meet some question
   dependent classifiers specified by me
2. Display the data in a list
3. Allow for modification of this list (= deletion/insertion
   of items),
4. Finally store the modified list in a new database
   or file.

### Entity-base Scenario:

1. Get some data stored in the database
2. Stepwisely display each entity:

   - Let the participant edit one ore more attributes of the currently displayed entity
   - Update the original entity in the original database

### Additional requirements:

- Ideally, the survey system/library can be either used with my **Java** database code since I have already programmed a bunch of SQL-queries or somehow integrates with CouchDB. However, if there is a solution that does not meet this point, I am open to it :)
- It does not necessarily have to be online/a remote service, I am fine
  with a native application.
- The data I am working it is highly sensitive, thus, I must not upload
  any data to third-party servers.

Does anyone know a library that would actually meet my requirements? Since I really have to find a solution or else start implementing one myself as soon as possible, I would highly appreciate your suggestions, reports of experience, and general hints on this. Thanks a lot in advance, I am happy about any feedback!

P.S.: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687720/open-source-survey-questionnaire-engine-for-java) led me to **JSurveyLib**. The responder, however, suggests **JCaiF** which seems to be not that well documented. Has anyone of you used this framework before?